# validating parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

under script tag  i need to include codes for "value must be nonnegative" when a negative number is entered. i have already included codes for "value must be a number."

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test_ifinteger(testcontrol, nameoffield) {
      var x = 0;
      var isok = true;
      var teststring = testcontrol.value;
      if (teststring.length == 0)
          return true;
      else {
          while (x < teststring.length) {
              if (teststring.charAt(x) < '0' || teststring.charAt(x) > '9')
                  isok = false;
              x++;
          }  //end while
          if (!isok) {
              alert(nameoffield + " must be a number!");
              testcontrol.focus();
          } //end else if(ok)
          return isok;

      }//end else if (teststring.length==0)
  } //end function

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the first char of the string, it will be "-" if its a negative number.

Use this:

```
  var negative = "-1234";

  if (negative[0] == '-')
      MessageBox.Show("Negative Number");
```

or add to your code:

```
while (x < teststring.length) {
          if (x == 0 && teststring.charAt(x) == '-')
              MessageBox.Show("Negative Number - Do what you want");
          if (teststring.charAt(x) < '0' || teststring.charAt(x) > '9')
              isok = false;
          x++;
```

Also, if its either negative or not a number, consider breaking the loop to avoid unnecessary loop iterations.
use the "break" command.

```
 if (x == 0 && teststring.charAt(x) == '-')
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Negative Number - Stopping loop");
    break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function isNumber(n) {
   return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
 }
function test_ifinteger(testcontrol, nameoffield) {

      var teststring = testcontrol.value;
      if(isNumber(teststring)) {
         var no=parseFloat(teststring); // or use parseInt
         if(no<0) {
           //negative
         }
      }
      else {
         //not a number
      }
 } 
 </script>
```